# Coprime action of simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, online-resources, simple-groups

Let $A$ act on $G$ coprimely by automorphism where $G$ is a nonabelian simple group. Does it imply that $|A|=p$? (where $p$ is a prime number)

If not, Is there any source that examines such cases separately and gives the cardinality of $C_G(A)$?

Comment: Well you haven't said what $p$ is.

Comment: @DerekHolt: It is added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that acting coprimely means $(|A|,|G|)=1$ and that $p$ is supposed to be a prime, I think the answer is no. I think (although I haven't checked carefully) that the only coprime automorphisms of finite simple groups are field automorphisms of groups of Lie type.

For example  ${\rm PSL}(2,2^{25})$ has order coprime to $5$ and has a field automorphism group of order $25$. Its centralizer is ${\rm PSL}(2,2)$.

And ${\rm PSL}(2,2^{35})$ has a field automorphism of order $35$ to which it is coprime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you suggest a source to me so that I can check the cardinality of $C_G(A)$?

Comment: Sorry, all I can think of is Carter's book "Finite Groups of Lie Type" for a general treatment of automorphism groups. For most fot he classical groups, field automorphism just act by applying the field automorphism to all elements of the matrices, so the centralizer is just the sam classical group over the fixed field of the field automorphism.